# Setting and using a variable (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, variables, video

I'm loading a text file using the FileReader API.  In the process I place the contents in a `<pre>` tag `fileDisplayArea.innerText = reader.result;`.  Later I want to use this content in the duringPlayback function that is triggered during the playback of a video. `video.ontimeupdate = function () { duringPlayback() };`

I don't want to pull in the loaded file's contents over and over and over again by placing it within the video.ontimeupdate function, so I thought I'd simply load the reader.result (or fileDisplayArea.innerText) content into a global variable where I could later perform the needed actions on the content within the video.ontimeupdate function.  But I can't seem to set the variable so that it can be used within the video.ontimeupdate function.  I was running in strict mode, but I've commented that out and it still doesn't work.

**How can I set the reader.result contents in a variable that can be used within the video.ontimeupdate function?**  I'm stumped. (And I'd like to run in strict mode, if possible.)

Thanks in advance,
Andrew

```
 // Assign an ontimeupdate event to the video element, and execute a function if the current playback position has changed
video.ontimeupdate = function () { duringPlayback() };

function duringPlayback() {
    document.getElementById("speed").innerHTML = (Math.round(video.playbackRate * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);

    // I need to use the var hostFile (reader.result) contents here. ###########

}


 // Load Tab Delimted File
var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
fileInput.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    var file = fileInput.files[0];
    var textType = /text.*/;
    if (file.type.match(textType)) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            // Entire file
            fileDisplayArea.innerText = reader.result;
            var hostFile = reader.result; //###########
        }
        reader.readAsText(file);
        //doIt(); //Normally doIt would be called from another function
    } else {
        fileDisplayArea.innerText = "File not supported!"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I thought I'd simply load the reader.result (or fileDisplayArea.innerText) content into a global variable

So just do that. Declare your variable outside of everything:

```
var hostFile;
video.ontimeupdate = function () { duringPlayback() };

function duringPlayback() {
  document.getElementById("speed").innerHTML = (Math.round(video.playbackRate * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);

  // I need to use the var hostFile (reader.result) contents here.
  console.log(hostFile);

}

var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
fileInput.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
  var file = fileInput.files[0];
  var textType = /text.*/;
  if (file.type.match(textType)) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        // Entire file
        fileDisplayArea.innerText = reader.result;
        hostFile = reader.result; //###########
    }
    reader.readAsText(file);
    //doIt(); //Normally doIt would be called from another function
  } else {
    fileDisplayArea.innerText = "File not supported!"
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried.  (Sorry that I didn't capture that line in my post.)  I previously had var hostFile = ""; (I thought I had to give it an initial value.), but have changed it to just var hostFile;  Now, instead of nothing the console returns "undefined".  I'm still stumped.  It seems this should be so easy!

Comment: It sounds like `duringPlayback` is getting called before `hostFile` gets set to the reader's results. You might want to setup a plunker/jsfiddle/codepen to better illustrate your issue

Comment: Doh!  I just smelled my own brain fart.  I was comparing what you had, line-by-line, with my code.  Within the reader.onload function I had "var hostFile = reader.result" instead of just "hostFile = reader.result".  Of course, I removed the "var" and now it works just as intended.  -  I'm still not good enough at this that I easily catch stupid mistakes like that.  Thank you.  Without you taking the time to post the correct script, I'm not sure how long it would have taken me to catch the error.  I'm sure it would have been awhile.  -  Thanks again, Andrew